# How to get sentence/text similarity of new corpus from a WIKI-doc2vec model?

Tags: python, gensim, cosine-similarity, doc2vec, sentence-similarity

I am working on a NLP project at the moment. One task is to compare how similar two news articles/titles are.

To do that, i have already trained a doc2vec model using English wikipeida articles on gensim library. Now i want to compare similarities of new text by inferring vectors from the wiki doc2vec model. 
One of the method i have tried is the gensim docvecs's 'similarity_unseen_docs' function. However, the result isn't really intuitive.
May i know are there any other way to get a similarity score with better performance? Or maybe some part of code is wrong?

Training of the doc2vec model:

```py
models = Doc2Vec(dm=1, dm_mean=1, vector_size=300, window=5, min_count=20, epochs =10, sample=0.001, negative=5, workers=cores)
```

Comparing similarity:

```py
arg1='China is  the leader in manufacturing electric vehicle'
arg2='The biggest electric car producer is China'

model.docvecs.similarity_unseen_docs(model=wikimodel, doc_words1=tokenize_text(arg1), 
                                         doc_words2=tokenize_text(arg2), alpha=0.025, min_alpha=0.0001, steps=50)
```

The output similarity score is only ~0.25 which doesn't seem to be good.

Here's the code for the training:

```py
from gensim.corpora.wikicorpus import WikiCorpus
from gensim.models.doc2vec import Doc2Vec, TaggedDocument
from gensim.models import KeyedVectors
from pprint import pprint
import multiprocessing

#read the wiki corpus
wiki = WikiCorpus("trend_analysis/enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2")

#define the class to convert wikicorpus into suitable form to train Doc2vec
class TaggedWikiDocument(object):
    def __init__(self, wiki):
        self.wiki = wiki
        self.wiki.metadata = True
    def __iter__(self):
        for content, (page_id, title) in self.wiki.get_texts():
            yield TaggedDocument([c for c in content], [title])

documents = TaggedWikiDocument(wiki)


cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()

#initialize a model and choose training method. (we use DM here)
models = Doc2Vec(dm=1, dm_mean=1, vector_size=300, window=5, min_count=20, epochs =10, sample=0.001, negative=5, workers=cores)

#building vocab for the model
models.build_vocab(documents)

#train the Doc2vec model
models.train(documents,total_examples=models.corpus_count, epochs=1)
```

Please let me know if the training is having any error that caused the inaccuracy for the inferring of unseen docs.

Comment: There may be errors in your training or other code. In particular, even the tiny excerpt you're showing isn't consistent in naming the `Doc2Vec` model(s) involved: there's `models`, `model`, and `wikimodel` – but only the definition of `models` is shown. You should show the code you used to train the `Doc2Vec` model, and check/show that the model gives some good results before then trying to use it on new texts.

Comment: One test could be: do `most_similar()` operations on known training article tags return expected related training articles? Another test could be: re-infer a vector for a training doc, then ask for that vec's `most_similar()` docs, and see if they're similar to asking for that same doc's `most_similar()` docs by tag.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've checked using the first method that you mentioned. By using the code `wikimodel.docvecs.most_similar(positive=["Electric vehicle"], topn=20)`. The returned article tags are like 'Hybrid Vehicle', 'Battery electric vehicle', etc Which is pretty relevant in my opinion.

Comment: Your training code looks generally correct, & your `most_similar()` results indicate the model is doing something meaningful, though it'd be more typical to use 10 to 20 training `epochs`, which could strengthen the model. It's not clear what your `tokenize_text()` function does, but the default one used by `WikiCorpus` will lowercase everything, meaning that the word `'china'` will be known to the model – but not `'China'`. So if your tokenization is leaving that capitalized, the word will be ignored as unknown during inference/`similarity_unseen_docs()`.

Comment: You could reuse `gensim.corpora.wikicorpus.tokenize` to ensure your later tokenization exactly matches how training texts were tokenized. I'd recommend more `epochs` during initial training. But note also: I'm not sure a model trained on the hundreds-to-thousands-of-words articles will give tight expected similarities on tiny 7-8 word texts. And, similarities should generally be interpreted relative to other similarities, moreso than some absolute measure/percentage of similarity. (If they rank text similarities well, they're working, even if not reaching some desired closeness to 1.0.)

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Yes, i did lower the characters of each word in my `tokenize_text() ` function. I think i will try on articles with more number of words to test the similarities and also increase the `epochs` as well.